# Ruby on Rails shopping cart: download and print options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopping-cart

I am building an online poster maker store with Ruby on Rails that gives the customer the option to either download a digital file for a generated poster or to have us print it for them and ship it to them. I am having troubles deciding where in my application to put this functionality. I am using a basic products, line_item, and cart structure.

Do I:

1) Make an option on the checkout that creates an Order if they decide to have us print the poster. If they just want the digital file it would just give them access on their user page after checkout.

2) Make a attribute on my line_item model that saves weather they want to download or print the file.

3) Something else entirely?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution! After talking to another developer friend, it hit me that the best solution might be to put all of the attributes for both printed and downloadable posters in the same products model and then expose only the information needed for each particular order.

For example,

If the order is to be printed by us, the user will be asked to fill out a shipping address form and asked what paper they want us to use. If they customer is just going to download the generated poster design these fields in the form will be hidden.

I believe that this is a much simpler solution then the two that I described above and will be the easiest to implement.